# Notify Mailing list of new entry?

Tags: members, email, notification

Is it possible to notify a mailing list when a new entry is submitted?

I know if is fairly easy to notify a member group when a entry is submitted, but I need to notify a mailing list everytime an entry is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control is the answer.

i found this version: http://www.eec.ms/forums/viewthread/573/

Comment: Version doe snot work here EE v2.6.1 - Build Date: 20130506 Fatal error: Call to a member function get_channels() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/zoetewildernis.nl/httpdocs/zw/expressionengine/third_party/mx_notify_control/ext.mx_notify_control.php on line 107

Answer (score 1):

With [Postmaster](https://www.objectivehtml.com/postmaster/features) you can send emails for anything, so it's possible.

Comment: Postmaster actually isn't capable of sending email using the native mailing list module. The native mailing list module is probably the worst way to send email, so Postmaster doesn't support it. A huge portion of those emails will never be received, as they will be marked as spam. This is why MailChimp or CampaignMonitor is recommended. I honestly doubt I will ever support the mailing list module simple because it's such a bad practice to use it.

Comment: Appreciate the recommendation though, thanks!